# Apache & SFTP permissions on AWS EC2 Linux hosting

Tags: linux, apache, permissions

Using SSH I've granted access to my SFTP clients user "ec2-user" with the following command:

sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html

However I also need to grant access to Apache which I can do with the following command:

sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html

I assumed this would grant access to both, but this is not the case. How can I apply the command to both ec2-user & Apache at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have executed **chown** commands, you did next: at first you've changed the owner of `/var/www/html` to `ec2-user`, and with next command you've changed the owner and owner group to apache. You can set only one pair of owner:owner-group to file or directory or whatever.

You have at least two ways to solve your task:

1. `usermod -a -G apache ec2-user` - this will add user `ec2-user` to `apache` group, after that, make sure, that permissions allows `apache` group members to manipulate files and directories as you need.
2. Create a subdirectory in `/var/www/html` with owner set to `ec2-user` and group set to main `apache` group and make sure that Apache could access it. You can configure it as a VirtualHost to separate it from original DocumentRoot.

Also, you have to set `ec2-user` home directory to `/var/www/html`, because even if it's has rights to access `/var/www/html`, it isn't necessary that it can access `/var` or `/var/www`.

Comment: Tried using "sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user" to add the user to Apache followed by "sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html" to provide Apache with access, but ec2-user still has no access. How do I set the users home directory to /var/www/html?

Comment: usermod ec2-user -d /var/www/html

Comment: the console gives me this error: usermod: user ec2-user is currently used by process 14717

Answer (score 0):

These instructions helped me to get this up and running very easily:

https://devanswers.co/configure-sftp-web-server-document-root/

Here's a cached version:
https://web.archive.org/web/20201203122712/https://devanswers.co/configure-sftp-web-server-document-root/

The idea here is to create a group like `sftp_users` and then set permissions to that group, adding the user to that group (the link above details all configurations and setup very well)